# Compiling GTK+3 by Using Meson

Tags: python, build, gtk, gtk3, meson-build

GTK+3 v3.24 is downloaded from Gitlab and extracted from zip file.
After running Meson, it gives the following error when `meson setup --prefix C:\Users\user\Desktop\gtk\gtk-gtk-3-24 builddir` command is run:

```
meson.build:359:0: ERROR: Git program not found.
```

No Git programs are installed on my machine (Windows 10 x64). But source code is downloaded. Meson and Ninja are installed by using pip command.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem that in addition to GTK sources you need to provide all required dependencies: some dependency is not found -> meson tries to use "fallback", i.e. download some subproject from git, probably [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Cwiiis1/gtk/-/blob/3.24.23/meson.build#L357) is glib dependency:

```
glib_dep       = dependency('glib-2.0', version: glib_req,
                            fallback : ['glib', 'libglib_dep'])
```

[Here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk#building-and-installing) you can find the list of some of required packages:

> You will also need various dependencies, based on the platform you are
> building for:
>
> - GLib
> - GdkPixbuf
> - GObject-Introspection
> - ...

But instead of painful process of setting up all these, why not just trying to use tool that is recommended to setup GTK on Windows? Check [gvsbuild](https://github.com/wingtk/gvsbuild) project or MSYS2, both described [here](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/).

Comment: I have already downloaded the required packages, but again it gives similar errors for some of them. Msys2 does not have latest verison of the many packages. Also there are another errors when using pip in Msys2. I have already checked gvsbuild, but I do not want to use MS Visual Studio.